# Resampling of raster very slow

Tags: r, gis, raster, sentinel2

)
I want to resample Sentinel-2 imagery so the resolution of two bands fit. I'm using raster::resample(raster1, raster2, method="ngb") for this, but the execution takes very very long. It is running for at least 15 minutes and so far I didn't obtain any output. I'm not sure if this will finish at some point.

I'm using bands 08 (10 m resolution) and 12 (20 m resolution) of Sentinel-2.

Resampling the same raster with QGIS takes a minute or so. I wanted to ask if this is a common problem with this function and if there is any workaround or another function/package I could use for that.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducable example of how you do a raster resampling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the function `gdalwarp` from the package `gdalUtils`.

Here there is an example on how to use `gdalwarp` for resampling:

https://csaybar.github.io/blog/2018/12/05/resample/

Here there is an example of a resampling function based on`gdalwarp`:

https://rdrr.io/github/AybarCL/Dorado/src/R/resample_R.R

If you have GRASS GIS installed, you could also have a look at the `fasterRaster` package that has a `fasterProjectRaster` function.

Comment: Amazing! You are my hero! :-) gdalwarp worked very well and finished in 50 seconds. But it's strange that raster::resample does not work for me... I let it run for over an hour without finishing. However, I will use gdalwarp instead :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `terra` package is faster, although I have not done a speed test for this task.

Same syntax and arguments:

```
resampled_raster <- terra::resample(raster1, raster2, method = "ngb")
```